# How many gadgets does Gadget have?

Tags: character, inspector-gadget

I know that Inspector Gadget has a dizzying amount of gadgets, but does anyone know how many gadgets Inspector Gadget actually has?

Comment: We don't know and we aren't meant to know. The running gag is that he is a walking gadget and has everything and anything he needs available to him. Similar to Batman's utility belt.

Comment: @sanpaco I think that's an answer right there.

Comment: **Banal trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.** I don't think this question is asking banal trivia. The answer to the question actually adds to the understanding of the show. Please don't broaden the horizon of off-topic(trivia) questions

Comment: I'm suggesting this should be closed under the too broad category rather than trivia

Comment: @Vishwa "we don't know. The answer isn't deliberately provided as a trope" is an acceptable answer to a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't know how many gadgets he has and we aren't meant to know as its not important to the plot. What is important to know is that he has, in your words, a dizzying amount of gadgets, all available to him literally at his fingertips whenever he needs them.

His seemingly unlimited supply of gadgets is a plot device and gag, not un-similar to other famous super-heroes such as Batman's utility belt (go go gadget shark rpllant anyone?), or Iron Man's suit. We don't care as an audience where or how so many gadgets are so readily available to these characters because the only thing we need to know is that they are technologically advanced and resourceful.

There are quite a few different tv tropes about this including *[New Powers as the Plot Demands](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NewPowersAsThePlotDemands)*, and *[Utility Belt](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UtilityBelt)*